# Program crash on copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have the following code I was testing:

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 class Stringtype{
     char* str;
     int length;
     public:
     Stringtype(){
         str='\0';
         length=0;
     }
     Stringtype(const Stringtype& s){
         cout<<"Constructor"<<endl;
         strcpy(this->str, s.str);
         this->length = s.length;
     }

     Stringtype(char* text){
         strcpy(this->str, text);
         this->length = strlen(str);
     }
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Stringtype s){
         stream<<"Value :"<<endl;
         for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
              cout<<(s.str)[i];
         }
         cout<<endl;
         stream<<"Length :"<<endl;
         stream<<s.length<<endl;
         return stream;
     }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, Stringtype& s){
         cout<<"Enter the string"<<endl<<endl;
         s.str = new char[30];
         cin>>s.str;
         s.length = strlen(s.str);
         return stream;
     }
 };

 int main(){
     Stringtype s1, s2;
     cin>>s1>>s2;
     cout<<s1<<s2;
     cout<<(s1>s2)<<endl;
     cout<<(s1<s2)<<endl;
     cout<<(s1==s2)<<endl;
     cout<<(s1+s2)<<endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

This code produces the following output (after the input is taken properly):

**Constructor**

and then crashes.

I can't seem to understand why...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: hint: where does `str` point to when you copy construct ?

Comment: Does your religion prohibit you from using debugger?

Comment: ah I get it now.
But... from where is the copy constructor being called? I am new to C++.
Is it being called when the operator<<() overloaded function is being called during output, to copy construct the parameter object?

Comment: @DebanikDawn copy constructor is called when you are passing `s` as value in `operator<<()`.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you guys so very much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually reserve memory for your internal memory representation of your string. You need to have a `new` *somewhere*. Otherwise you will write to memory you don't own, which is exactly what is happening here, right in the next line after the output you observe.

---

By the way: there should be no copy-construction here, your signature

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Stringtype s){
```

should read:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Stringtype& s){
```

Doesn't change the fact that you have errors in your memory handling though.

Comment: thank you so much for the help!
and I tried to make it `Stringtype&`. The problem I am facing is when I want to do `cout<<s1+s2;` it fails. (after overloading the operator+()). This is because operator+ returns an **object** and not a reference to the object
what should I do?

Comment: You are supposed to make it **const** StringType&. Then it will work with temporary objects.

Comment: Oh. Thank you!
I had no idea!

Comment: Using `vector<char>` instead of `new` will make life easier

Comment: @M.M While true, it might defeat the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: @M.M I know. But this was an assignment. And also a preparation for tomorrow's exam. So...

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Stringtype s)
to 
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Stringtype& s)

Take the reference for the string s

Comment: This does not address the actual problems and the operator will not take temporary objects even if you change it to what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing str="", instead str='\0';